# How to make onclick fire on a generated div

Tags: jquery

I have div(b) being generated by jquery when I press on  div(a). But then I can't use:

```
$('#b').on('click', function(){ alert('test')})
```

on div(b). Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Is it even possible?

Comment: I think they talk about it in documentation...

Comment: possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use event delegation feature of jQuery's [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$(document).on("click", "#b", function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Ya, thx for providing link to documentation, now OP knows where to search... ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff Thought to myself: the question is there now anyway, may as well give the standard response and get some rep for it...

Comment: Yeah, have some more :)

Answer (score -3):

Create `<div onclick="yourjavascriptfunction()"></div>` and write a function with same name. And it's done.

```
function yourjavascriptfunction(){
    //do your staff
}
```

Comment: The OP asked how to do this in jQuery

Comment: Tag is jQuery and nothing more. He just wanted to fix the problem.